# Pycharm terminal can't find /user/local/

Tags: bash, linux-mint

I am using Linux mint 20.3 and Pycharm CE 2021.3.2 version.

I am using bash with Pycharm's terminal.
I have a script in .bashrc which needs access to /usr/local/bin. Unfortunately, Pycharm's terminal doesn't seem to find it. I used the command line of course to explore the folder and I can confirm that this repo is not visible at all.
I used the classic terminal. There are no issues with it at all.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the Flatpak version, by chance?

Comment: No I am not using Flatpak.

Comment: @ajgringo619 Actually, after more investigation, it seems that Linux mint software manager installs Pycharm using Flatpak.

Comment: Unless you give `PyCharm` permission to see the root filesystem, what you're trying will not work. I would suggest downloading `PyCharm` from the main JetBrains site.

Comment: PyCharm installed via `snap` with `--classic` as `sudo snap install pycharm-professional --classic` has no such issue.